# Ajax dynamic S_SESSION generating doesnt update the SESSION values

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, autocomplete

I have ajax autocomplete for search field that searches for related products. In order not to show a products already associated with the product I made this function:

```
function getRelatedProducts($pid){
$str='SELECT distinct related_id FROM related_products WHERE product_id="'.$pid.'" ';
$result=mysql_query($str) or die('Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'<br /> Query:'.$query);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$str='';
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if($i==0) $str=$row[0];
    else $str.=','.$row[0];
}
return $str;
}    
$_SESSION['related_products']=getRelatedProducts($_GET['id']);
```

This way I am storing the new array values of products ids that are already assoc with the product..
After that here is the autocomplete search query:

```
$query = "SELECT id,bg_product_name,model FROM products WHERE     
(bg_product_name LIKE '%".$q."%' or model LIKE '%".$q."%') AND        
active='1' and id NOT IN ('".$_SESSION['related_products']."') group by id LIMIT 11";
```

but the query always shows same products - even they are already assoc with the product.. Please help me to find where I am wrong..
Thank you in advance

Comment: I see no jquery, nor ajax here, nor how it is related to the question

Comment: @RoyalBg He's calling this PHP function via AJAX from jQuery UI Autocomplete.

Comment: should I copy all 3 files involved in the case just to prove it uses jquery and ajax? The problem is in copied queries that's why I focus your attention on them..

Comment: @thecore7 no, but when the problem is not related, just don't mention it, or just don't put it on high priority. Your summary starts with `ajax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting quotes around the entire `related_products` list, so it's not treating it as a list of things to exclude, it's just one value. Assuming `related_id` is an integer, use:

```
$query = "SELECT id,bg_product_name,model 
          FROM products 
          WHERE     
            (bg_product_name LIKE '%".$q."%' or model LIKE '%".$q."%') 
            AND        
            active='1' and id NOT IN (".$_SESSION['related_products'].") 
          group by id 
          LIMIT 11";
```

Comment: Barmar, I changed to yours and here is how the query looks: SELECT id,bg_product_name,model 
          FROM products 
          WHERE     
            (bg_product_name LIKE '%new%' or model LIKE '%new%') 
            AND        
            active='1' and id NOT IN () 
          group by id 
          LIMIT 11 - it is wrong because not in doesnt contain array of ids. ?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in the PHP?

Comment: yes it is on the top of the file, but even without it SESSION is visible in the file

Comment: here is how my query looks, but returns wrong results: SELECT id,bg_product_name,model FROM products WHERE (bg_product_name LIKE '%new%' or model LIKE '%new%') AND active='1' and id NOT IN ('752,753,754') group by id LIMIT 11

Comment: As you can see, you have quotes around the list of numbers, so it's just a single value to compare against, not a list. I don't see why you're getting an empty list when you remove the quotes. It should be exactly the same, except no quotes around `752,753,754`.

Comment: yes, but if I set it to yours and if $_session is empty the query stops. If not empty - it still shows wrong result..

Comment: Are all product IDs greater than 0? Use `id NOT IN (0,". $_SESSION['related_products'].")`. That ensures that there's always something in the list.

Comment: Barmar, do you think that $_SESSION['related_products'] is being updated properly or I need first to destroy it and than to regenerate it?

Comment: Barmar, I defined if(empty($_SESSION['related_products'])) $_SESSION['related_products']='0'; and changed to your query and now it works properly ! Thank you for helping me !! I accept the answer !